# JQuery scroll animation flashes home screen for split second

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've coded a menu using bootstrap that scrolls to different parts of my page using JQuery, but for a split second before it scrolls the home screen flashes up. I don't know why it happens or how to stop it.

```
$("#butHome").click(function() {
$(".nav li").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#home").offset().top
}, 300);
});
$("#but1").click(function() {
$(".nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#section1").offset().top
}, 300);
});
$("#but2").click(function() {
$(".nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#section2").offset().top
}, 300);
}); 
$("#but3").click(function() {
$(".nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#section3").offset().top
}, 300);
});
$("#but4").click(function() {
$(".nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#section4").offset().top
}, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the anchor link makes the page scroll to the top of the page before the animation starts. You may prevent this default browser behaviour by adding the following within your handler:

```
$('.upp').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.scrollTo( '#up', 800 );
});
```

**COPIED**

Comment: It seems that your scrollTo code is repeated many times so it's better to create a function with two arguments or perhaps one to handle that.

Comment: Hey thanks I ended up working that out a while back but I appreciate you take the time to help

Comment: No Problem ... Always there :D